# How to get rid of this page flickering?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sticky, scrolltop

I am working on one project, have an issue with `jquery/js` logic of adding/removing class for sticky menu,

**Sample Page:**
https://anish.kickpages.com/stickymenu/

Try to scroll very slowing and you will notice flickering.

**Code:**

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var jsHeight = $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().height(); 
  $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().css('height', jsHeight);

  $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().addClass('remove-jump');


  $(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
      $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().css('height', 0);
      $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').addClass('fixed-header-top');
      $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').css('background', '');
    }
    else {
      $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().css('height', jsHeight);
      $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').removeClass('fixed-header-top');
      $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').css('background', '');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I resolved this issue for top position by commenting, $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().css('height', 0); $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().css('height', jsHeight); lines for first section.

Answer (score 0):

Visited your awesome page and scrolled down slowly, but could not see any flickering at all. I'm running Firefox on Ubuntu 18.04.

Edit: Did not mean to post this as an answer

Comment: With Chrome I get the flickering.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to put `#section_o7kn8h_1531206224` inside a div with a fixed height.

Comment: Thanks but Not possible as this structure built from long back and everything is interdependent, so many  by following same structure if we can do something to remove flickering event.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 100) {
        $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().css('height', 0);
        $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').addClass('fixed-header-top');
        $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').css('background', '');
    }
    else {
        $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').parent().css('height', jsHeight);
        $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').removeClass('fixed-header-top');
        $('#section_o7kn8h_1531206224').css('background', '');
    }
});
```

You can remove the above and directly add the  `fixed-header-top` class to `#section_o7kn8h_1531206224` in the html.

Comment: Thanks, but we can not add class directly as it is not static page and we need smooth fade effect on scroll. These pages going to be dynamic, any section can be sticky and on scroll we need smooth fade effect + remove that sticky div + no jumping in place of sticky section :)

Comment: What is the exact thing you intend to do with the snippet above? I see that the flicker is happening because of scroll event being called repeatedly, and toggling the class "fixed-header-top" and the height of the parent div

Comment: On scrolltop amount 100, I want to make one of my section to be sticky and non-sticky on opposite action. We added height to add smoothness in content jump due to position change from relative to fixed.